# How to findout user's connection details in linkedin api using php

Tags: php, linkedin-api

```
https://api.linkedin.com//v1/people/~/connections?oauth2_access_token=my key&modified=new&format=json
```

using this key i can get my connections . if i want to get user's connection details where i should place the user's id in the above URL?
or is there any other way to find out the user's information?

Answer (score 0):

I think your link's format is incorrect:

```
https://api.linkedin.com//v1/people/~/connections?oauth2_access_token=my key&format=json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a user profile you have to use the oauth2_access_token of this user.